# I want run a job on buissness days only in the python schedule module

Tags: python, python-schedule

does anyone know how to do this in the python schedule module? there is little to no documention on what I want to do.

my code is:

```
schedule.every().day.at("21:05:00").do(turn_off)
schedule.every().Monday.at("06:00").do(turn_on)
schedule.every().Tuesday.at("06:00").do(turn_on)
schedule.every().Wednesday.at("06:00").do(turn_on)
schedule.every().Thursday.at("06:00").do(turn_on)
schedule.every().Friday.at("06:00").do(turn_on)
schedule.every().Monday.at("07:40").do(turn_off)
schedule.every().Tuesday.at("07:40").do(turn_off)
schedule.every().Wednesday.at("07:40").do(turn_off)
schedule.every().Thursday.at("07:40").do(turn_off)
schedule.every().Friday.at("07:40").do(turn_off)
schedule.every().Monday.at("16:05").do(turn_on)
schedule.every().Tuesday.at("16:05").do(turn_on)
schedule.every().Wednesday.at("16:05").do(turn_on)
schedule.every().Thursday.at("16:05").do(turn_on)
schedule.every().Friday.at("16:05").do(turn_off)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a try and confirm if it works for you.

#### Run schedule from Monday to Friday

```
schedule.every().monday.to(friday).at("06:00").do(job)
schedule.every().monday.to(friday).at("07:40").do(job)
```